# I want to correct this code for images, what change need to do..?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Currently i am recognzing a face, means i have to find a face which we have to test is in training database or not..! So, i have to decide yes or no..

Yes means find image, and no means print message that NO IMAGE IN DATABASE. I have a program, Currently this program is finding a correct image correctly, but even when there is no image, even it shows other image which not matches.. Actually it should print NO IMAGE IN DATABASE.

So, How to do..?

Here is a Test and training images data on this link.

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g6e59fe8105a6e6389994740914b7b2fc99eb3e445

My Program is in terms of different four .m files, and it is here,we have to run only first code.. and remaining 3 are functions, it is also given here..**

```
 clear all

 clc

 close all

TrainDatabasePath = uigetdir('D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2006a\work', 'Select training database path' );

TestDatabasePath = uigetdir('D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2006a\work', 'Select test database path');

prompt = {'Enter test image name (a number between 1 to 10):'};

dlg_title = 'Input of PCA-Based Face Recognition System';

num_lines= 1;

def = {'1'};

TestImage = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);

TestImage = strcat(TestDatabasePath,'\',char(TestImage),'.jpg');

im = imread(TestImage);

T = CreateDatabase(TrainDatabasePath);

[m, A, Eigenfaces] = EigenfaceCore(T);

OutputName = Recognition(TestImage, m, A, Eigenfaces);

SelectedImage = strcat(TrainDatabasePath,'\',OutputName);

SelectedImage = imread(SelectedImage);

imshow(im)

title('Test Image');

figure,imshow(SelectedImage);

title('Equivalent Image');

str = strcat('Matched image is : ',OutputName);

disp(str)

function T = CreateDatabase(TrainDatabasePath)

TrainFiles = dir(TrainDatabasePath);

Train_Number = 0;

for i = 1:size(TrainFiles,1)

if

not(strcmp(TrainFiles(i).name,'.')|strcmp(TrainFiles(i).name,'..')|strcmp(TrainFiles(i).name,'Thu mbs.db'))

Train_Number = Train_Number + 1; % Number of all images in the training database

end

end

T = [];

for i = 1 : Train_Number

    str = int2str(i);
    str = strcat('\',str,'.jpg');
    str = strcat(TrainDatabasePath,str);
    img = imread(str);
    img = rgb2gray(img);
    [irow icol] = size(img);
    temp = reshape(img',irow*icol,1);   % Reshaping 2D images into 1D image vectors
    T = [T temp]; % 'T' grows after each turn                    
end

function [m, A, Eigenfaces] = EigenfaceCore(T)

m = mean(T,2); % Computing the average face image m = (1/P)*sum(Tj's) (j = 1 : P)

Train_Number = size(T,2);

A = [];

for i = 1 : Train_Number

    temp = double(T(:,i)) - m; 

 Ai = Ti - m

    A = [A temp]; % Merging all centered images

end

L = A'*A; % L is the surrogate of covariance matrix C=A*A'.

[V D] = eig(L); % Diagonal elements of D are the eigenvalues for both L=A'*A and C=A*A'.

L_eig_vec = [];

for i = 1 : size(V,2)

    if( D(i,i)>1 )
        L_eig_vec = [L_eig_vec V(:,i)];
    end
end

Eigenfaces = A * L_eig_vec; % A: centered image vectors

function OutputName = Recognition(TestImage, m, A, Eigenfaces)

ProjectedImages = [];

Train_Number = size(Eigenfaces,2);

for i = 1 : Train_Number

    temp = Eigenfaces'*A(:,i); % Projection of centered images into facespace
    ProjectedImages = [ProjectedImages temp]; 
end

InputImage = imread(TestImage);

temp = InputImage(:,:,1);

[irow icol] = size(temp);

InImage = reshape(temp',irow*icol,1);

Difference = double(InImage)-m; % Centered test image

ProjectedTestImage = Eigenfaces'*Difference; % Test image feature vector

Euc_dist = [];

for i = 1 : Train_Number

    q = ProjectedImages(:,i);
    temp = ( norm( ProjectedTestImage - q ) )^2;
    Euc_dist = [Euc_dist temp];
end

[Euc_dist_min , Recognized_index] = min(Euc_dist);

OutputName = strcat(int2str(Recognized_index),'.jpg');
```

**So, how to generate error massege when no image matches..?**

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your application appears to find the most similar image (you appear to be using Euclidean distance as you measure of similarity), and return it. There doesn't seem to be any concept of whether the image "matches" or not.

Define a threshold on similarity, and then determine whether your most similar image meets that threshold. If it does, return it, otherwise display an error message.